# ClosedXML: Is there a way of finding the worksheet position of a table row

Tags: excel, closedxml

Using ClosedXML to insert data into an existing Excel document, I need to move the part of the worksheet under a table down for a number of rows by inserting rows into the worksheet, not into the table.

Is there a way to find the row number `N` in the respective worksheet for a table row, which one gets e.g. by `IXLTable.LastRow()`, such, that `IXLWorksheet.Row(N)` will point to the row, in which the table's last row is contained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IXLTable.LastRow().RowNumber()` to get the row number.